# Mutual Information between the mean of normally-distributed random variables and another variable

Tags: normal-distribution, random-variable, information-theory, mutual-information

Given normally-distributed (possibly dependent) random variables $X_1 \dots X_n$, their mean $X=\frac{1}{n} \sum_iX_i$, and another discrete r.v. $Y$, can we relate $MI(X,Y)$ with the individual $MI(X_1, Y)\dots MI(X_n, Y)$? I'm also interested in lower/upper bounds if no exact expression exists.

Thanks!

Comment: You said "another *discrete* r.v. Y", but $X$ and $X_i$ have continuous distributions.  Did you mean "and another *separate* r.v. Y", meaning that $Y$ is also continuous?  Or did you mean that the $X$'s are continuous normal r.v.'s and $Y$ is discrete?